# node/express api url params

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i'm making an api using nodejs/express and i'm in doubt of what is the best way to query the params and get the result from the db. i'm doing like this but I dont think it's good. is there a best and more optimised way of doing it

```
router.get("/all", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let data = await Items.find();

    if (req.query.lang && req.query.category) {
      data = await Items.find({
        lang: req.query.lang,
        category: req.query.category,
      });
    } else if (req.query.lang) {
      data = await Items.find({ lang: req.query.lang });
    } else if (req.query.category) {
      data = await Items.find({ category: req.query.category });
    } else {
      data = await Items.find();
    }

    res.status(200).send(data);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code *works*, however there is one flaw and something I would like to note.

The flaw:

At the start you are using

```
let data = await Items.find();
```

So, no matter if there is a category or lang in query, you are doing a request to database to find all items at the start. This consumes server resources without any reason (as data is being replaced later).

I would declare the variable on top like this

```
let data
```

and leave the final condition to make the route parameter-absence-proof

```
else { // no filters
  data = await Items.find()
}
```

Notes on how to improve the code:

1 Shorten the vars

Since objects in JavaScript are always passed by reference (multiple variables reference the same object), there is no harm in doing this on top of the function:

```
let lang = req.query.lang
let category = req.query.category
```

This will make code more readable

2 Use single condition to query with any possible filters (and even without)

```
let conditions = req.query
```

**or** you may want to sanitize/transform the data coming in request

```
let conditions = sanitize(req.query)
```

then you can pass the conditions object to .find(), it will probably work like this

```
data = await Items.find( conditions )
```

So if conditions object is null, find will not use any filters.
If conditions object has *lang* key, it will use *lang* filter, etc